# Existence of a Frechet topology on the dual of a barreled space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I have a Hausdorff separated locally convex barreled space $(X,\tau)$  with topological dual $X^*$. My questions are:

$Q_1$ Is there a topology $\tau^*$ on $X^*$ that is finer than the weak-star topology $w^*$ such that $(X^*,\tau^*)$  is Frechet?

$Q_2$ If the answer for $Q_1$ is negative what extra conditions need be fulfilled so that $Q_1$ gets a positive answer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite often negative. For example, if $(X,\tau)$ is itself a Frechet space, then there is a Frechet topology on $X^*$ finer than the weak*-topology if and only if $X$ is Banach.

For the proof one considers the so-called inductive topology on $X^*$ (which is the inductive topology w.r.t. all embeddings of the Banach spaces whose unit balls are the closed absolutely convex equi-continuous sets) and applies the closed graph theorem to see that the Frechet topology is finer than the inductive topology. Then the open mapping theorem shows that those topologies are in fact equal. Finally, Baire's theorem implies that there is a single equi-continuous set which absorbs all others and this implies that $X$ is normed (hence Banach).

To have the dual of the barrelled space $X$ Frechet you need that $X$ has a fundamental *sequence* of bounded sets, that is $(B_n)_n$ is a sequence of bounded sets such that every bounded set is contained in some $B_n$.

This is part of Grothendieck's definition of (DF)-spaces (which need not be barrelled but only "countably quasi-barrelled").

Comment: I want to see if I understood your answer completely. First, if $(X,\tau)$ is Frechet but not normable (or Banach) then the answer is negative. So, it seems that completeness is in the way since for a normed barreled space the answer is positive. What is your opinion about that?  For the second part, what topology did you take on the dual to make it Frechet?  Please include some references. Thank you.

Comment: It is not complteness "in the way" but existence of a fundamental sequence of bounded sets. A metrizable space has such a sequence if and only if it is normable.

Comment: So it seems that if the space is metrizable then it should be normable and we get a positive answer. However, that answers only partially my original questions. Thank you anyways.