# Frechet topology finer than a given locally convex topology

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Under what conditions given a locally convex space $(X,\tau)$ there exists a Frechet topology $\mu$, that is, $\mu$  is locally convex metrizable and complete such that $\mu$  is finer than $\tau$?

Comment: Metrizability means you can define the locally convex topology with a countable collection of seminorms. Now $\mu$, being finer, would need more seminorms than $\tau$ in order to be defined. So you need $X$ to be metrizable.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I think you misread the question. The finer topology $\mu$ is metrizable not $\tau$. Think about the weak topology of a Banach space which admits the strong topology which is Frechet and finer than the weak topology. Clearly the weak topology is not necessarily metrizable.

Comment: I don't think that this question has a simple and useful answer, in general. Do have a concrete situation in mind?

Comment: @Jochen This question is a simplification of my previous one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970866/existence-of-a-frechet-topology-on-the-dual-of-a-barreled-space. Per our previous discussion concerning that question, I understand that on the dual of a Frechet space we can have a Frechet topology finer than the weak-star topology only if the space is a Banach space. However in general there might be non-Frechet spaces for which we can have a Frechet topology on its dual finer than the weak-star topology (e.g. a normed space). I simplified the question with that goal in mind.

Comment: @NeutralElement: You are right. I quickly though some cardinality argument could be used, but I overlooked the fact that a single $\mu$ seminorm can dominate infinitely many $\tau$ norms, as in the Banach space example you mentioned.